# [RDP-LYNC]How to sharing desktops or applications to Lync client or server?Is there any third-party libraries to implement RDP protocol?

Tags: ms-office, rdp, skype-for-business, lync-2013

We are developing a multimedia conference application and want to connect to Lync or Skype for Business.

Now we can transfer video stream (H264) and audio stream between Skype and our client.

But sharing stream stuck us,especially parsing the RDP protocol.
We have got the RDP stream,but how to get sharing contents?(Only the graphics data)
Our application run on Linux, Mac and Windows(mostly on Linux).

So is there any third-party solutions to deal with the RDP?
As I known, Polycom has completed this function.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep noted that the Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) was replaced by Video Based Screen Sharing (VBSS) when using Skype for business. See [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/314-black-or-frozen-screen-during-screensharing-in-skype-for-business-2016.html) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt756736.aspx) for more infos. As VBSS is the new standard, this might explain your issue. A possible solution might be to check how you can start using Video Based Screen Sharing (VBSS). I wouldn´t start building something on RDP as Microsoft might remove that in further version as there is VBSS.

However as you didn´t specify more infos for your "Solution" its not easy to give you and advise. Keep also noted that this isn´t the case for Lync. But as you specified Skype for Business and Lync I´m not sure if you see the issues with both server versions.

Comment: The VBSS is another question puzzled me.

Comment: The VBSS is another question puzzled me.
I have analyzed the behavior of Lync 2015 when sharing screen to another Lync. When sharing the desktop,there are two streams:one H264 stream(the graphics contents) and one RDP stream(including the whole message sequence).When sharing applications,there is only one RDP stream. So is there any documents about the VBSS feature?